# JSF value binding - changing the iFrame src refreshes the whole page

Tags: html, iframe, jsf-2

I have an `iframe` which dynamically change the value via `JSF Backing Bean`.

```
<iframe src="#{myBean.url}" />
```

While changing the `src` value of the `iframe`, somehow it refreshes my whole page.
I only need to refresh the `iframe` not the whole page.
How can I stop refreshing the whole page but only the `iframe` ?

Comment: post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it inside a JSF component with a given id that you're going to rerender via AJAX.

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Update iframe">
        <f:ajax render=":iframe-holder"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="iframe-holder" layout="block">
    <iframe src="#{myBean.url}">
        Iframes not supported
    </iframe>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And change the url in command button's action method or in any other way.

Comment: This was happening only with some IE updates. Now it doesn't refresh the whole page. Thanks